# Why do local variables that reference a global object seem to violate function scope?

Tags: javascript

I have this simple `example()` function. Now I've learned a little about function scope in javascript. But what baffles me is that local variables that refer to a global object, seem to violate function scope (or my understanding of it):

```
// https://jsfiddle.net/vnmscgsa/1/

var values = {
    'Extra level of nesting': {
        keyOne: 'one',
        keyTwo: 'two'    
    }
};

var example = function(values) {

    function setValue(value) {
      var data = values[value]; // a local copy of the values object
      data.keyOne = 'twenty'; // should only influence the local copy
    }

    for (var value in values) {
      setValue(value);
      console.log(values[value]);
    }

};

example(values); // will log "Object { keyOne: "twenty", keyTwo: "two" }"
```

I would say that the output of the `example()` function should be `"Object { keyOne: "one", keyTwo: "two" }"`, because the `data` variable in the `setValue` function is scoped to that function (so a copy of the global object that doesn't have any influence on it).

---

*The problem doesn't exist when referencing a string instead of an object: https://jsfiddle.net/gbyvh8t2/1/*

Comment: Since you are passing object, it won't be cloned. Since both of them share the same reference, the modification you made locally, is affecting the global object too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var data = values[value]; // a local copy of the values object
```

You are copying the **value** of `values[value]` to `data`.

That value is a *reference* to the object (because you only ever deal in references when accessing JavaScript objects).

You now have a local variable (`data`) and property (whatever `values[value]` resolves as) which each contain a reference to the same object.

The variables themselves are still in their original scopes. You've just passed a value between them.